# SQL Server Compact 4.0 database not detected after ClickOnce deploy

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I have a WPF C# application and an SQL Server Compact 4.0 database. Initially I had my Data Source pointing to the location of the database like this:

```
public static SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"C:\VSP Road Maintenance Solution\VSPApp_Mono\VSPApp\VSPCompactDatabasse.sdf");
```

This worked great on my local machine but when I wanted to package the application (ClickOnce), it didn't work on the client's machine. After going through MSDN documentation on creating an ms sql server compact database and deploying it and other related similar issues such as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c(v=vs.110).aspx

I tried to access the `AppDomain` via C# like (in `App.xaml.cs`):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); // Pick desired process
    p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime; // Assign priority

    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\VSP Road Maintenance Solution\VSPApp_Mono\VSPApp");
}
```

And now to create a connection to the database I just:

```
public static string dbFileName = "VspCompactDatabase.sdf";
SqlCeConnection sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\" +dbFileName);
```

This works on my local machine too, but when I create the ClickOnce package. The application does not seem to find the database. All the prerequisite software gets installed. Why is it that when the application is deployed on a different machine, the seems to be no connection with the database?

Comment: Your code is assuming that Sql Compact is installed on the client system.  Does your application install sql compact during installation?  If so, can you post the code that establishes your local db?

Comment: No my code does not assume that sql compact is installed. During installation the application will check if it is installed or not (i.e. on the client machine) and installed it. There is no code for this because I just included it in the prerequisite section.

Comment: @ErikEJ non what so ever! I mean even after publishing the software I can see the database.sdf.deploy file is there

Comment: have you tried adding some logging around the database file, can you access that directory, can you open the file using a standard file stream etc...

Comment: @AwkwardCoder create a log file for the database? Okay let me search what that is all about

Comment: no add some logging to your application